# Adding multiple ForeginKeys in one column PostgeSQL

Tags: postgresql, django-models, psycopg2

I am trying to add every object in a table to a single column in another table to have sort by all the objects relating to that column very easily.

To do I am running this command through psycopg2

`cursor.execute("UPDATE  \"tablename\" SET \"nameofcoloumn\" = unnest(ARRAY([3,5])) WHERE id = 3; ")`

and it gives me `psycopg2.errors.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "["`

but when I do,

`cursor.execute("UPDATE  \"tablename\" SET \"nameofcoloumn\" = 5 WHERE id = 3; ")`

it works. Is there any other way to link the two lists? I am using django to create the models for the table if that matters, but it shouldn't.

Comment: That makes no sense. A column can contain only a single value per row.

Comment: A column can have an array when the column is initialized using [] but you cant initialize an array of foreign keys. So basically what I am trying to ask is there any other way to create an array with foreign keys or some other way to create an array with a relationship to another table.

Comment: Ah, I see. No, that is not possible. That's why it is usually better to normalize the data model and to avoid arrays.